# When will the hour hand be on a whole number if it jerks and it's speed is increasing?

Tags: sequences-and-series, modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations, diophantine-equations

I was recently introduced to modular arithmetic and was playing around with clock related questions, when I thought, if we ignore the minute-hand and second-hand, the hour hand will be on a whole number every 60 minutes.

But if the hour hand jumps directly a certain distance, like say 3 minutes every 1 minute (let's call it $n$), we can see, it will be on a whole number every 20 minutes as $60 \div 3 = 20$. And if 60 was not divisible by $n$, then we can multiply it by 60, for example, if $n=7$, then the answer will be $7 \times 60 = 420$ . So, the first time the hour hand will be on a whole number will be in 60 minutes (or 60 steps) and it will be on the number 7 on the clock.

Now what if the hour-hand gains a constant speed every step? For example, 3 + 5 + 7 + 9 + ...

As in, on the first step it covers 3 minutes, on second step it covers another 5 minutes, so a total of 8 minutes in two steps, and it continues on, going around the 12-hour clock until it reaches exactly a whole number.

I tried to solve it as follows:

$3 + 5 + 7 + 9 + 11 + 13 + ...$ upto  m steps

taking 3 from all numbers gives

$3m + (0 + 2 + 4 + 6 + 8 + ...$ upto m steps)

$= 3m + 2 (0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ...$ upto m steps) (taking 2 common)

$= 3m + 2 (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ...$ upto (m-1) steps)

$ = 3m + \frac{2(m-1)(m)}{2} $

$ = 3m + (m-1)m$

$ = 3m + m^2 - m$

$ = m^2 + 2m$

Which should be equal to $60n$ I think, (I'm a little confused at this point), but then that gives me a single equation with 2 variables. How do I solve this?

Do I need to put every possible value one by one or there can be a generalized formula here, which can help me to come up with a solution in least number of steps with other values of n, and 12 or 60 as well?

(Note: As you can probably see, I'm not very good at maths, so please try to keep it simple, while giving as much information as possible. I'm willing to study further if needed. Thank you).

Comment: +1 : imaginative question.

Comment: I don't understand the setup of the problem; if I understand correctly, the minute hand is at a whole number every 5 minutes on a normal clock, and so it is at a whole number 12 times every 60 minutes. If it jumps 3 minutes every minute, then it will be at a whole number every 5 minutes, at the numbers 3, 6, 9 and 12. How do you conclude that the minute hand will be at a whole number every $60/3=20$ minutes?

Comment: @Servaes, you're right, I'm actually talking about the hour hand while saying minute hand all along. Does that make sense? If yes, then I would edit the question.

Comment: @rohitanshu That makes a lot more sense, yes.

Comment: @Servaes, thank you so much for pointing out that silly mistake. I've edited the question.

Comment: The description is still confusing since it talks about being on a whole number when actually you mean it does a whole number of revolutions.

Comment: @user2661923 thank you. :)

Comment: @JaapScherphuis, No, I mean  being on a whole number. You can imagine it as coinciding with another series which goes 60 minutes in each step. The total steps taken by both the series doesn't have to be same, just that one of the series gets to where the other series has already been.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your mathematical question; you want to find the smallest positive integer $m$ such that
$$m^2+2m=60n,$$
for some integer $n$. This will be the number of steps $m$ until you reach the first whole number $n$. Phrased in terms of modular arithmetic, you are looking to solve the congruence
$$m^2+2m\equiv0\pmod{60}.$$
A very general and powerful observation is that if $m$ is a solution to the congruence, then so is $m\pm60$. So if any solution exist, then can keep adding or subtracting $60$ to get a solution in the range $0\leq m<60$. This already greatly limits the search for a solution.

In this case, because $60$ is not a very large number, and the left hand side is a fairly simple function, by some educated trial and error you can find that
$$10^2+2\cdot10\equiv0\pmod{60},$$
which shows that after $10$ steps you reach the number $2$. Then it is not hard to check that no smaller positive integer $m$ satisfies the congruence.

---

Here is an approach that is applicable more generally: If $n$ is a positive integer with prime factorization $n=\prod_pp^{n_p}$, then by the Chinese remainder theorem the solutions to a congruence
$$f(m)\equiv0\pmod{n},$$
correspond bijectively to the simultaneous solutions of the system of congruences
$$f(m)\equiv0\pmod{p^{n_p}}\ \text{ for each prime $p$ dividing $n$}.$$
In this case we have $60=2^2\times3\times5$ and so it suffices to solve
\begin{eqnarray*}
m^2+2m&\equiv0\pmod{2^2},\\
m^2+2m&\equiv0\pmod{3},\\
m^2+2m&\equiv0\pmod{5}.
\end{eqnarray*}
The moduli are now so small that it is easy to simply check all possibilities; we find that
\begin{eqnarray*}
m&\equiv0,2\pmod{2^2},\\
m&\equiv0,1\pmod{3},\\
m&\equiv0,3\pmod{5}.
\end{eqnarray*}
These congruences give $2\times2\times2=8$ solutions to the original congruence, and they are
$$m\equiv0,10,18,28,30,40,48,58\pmod{60}.$$
This shows that indeed $10$ is the smallest positive integer that satisfies the congruence.

---

If you would like to remove 'guessing' or 'trial and error' completely, then there are general methods to solve the system of simple congruences above. These use the (rather amazing) fact that modulo prime numbers you can use a lot of algebraic tricks you know for real numbers. For example, the quadratic formula still works modulo every prime number $p>2$. So the congruence
$$m^2+2m\equiv0\pmod{3},$$
leads to the solutions
$$m\equiv\frac{-2\pm\sqrt{2^2-4\cdot1\cdot0}}{2\cdot1}\equiv\frac{-2\pm\sqrt{4}}{2}\equiv-1\pm1\pmod{3},$$
where of course $-1+1\equiv0\pmod{3}$ and $-1-1\equiv-2\equiv1\pmod{3}$. You can solve the equation modulo $5$ in the exact same way.

Comment: Interesting. So just to be clear, we can't use 60 (or any $n$) directly, but rather have to know it's prime factors first, and then use them one-by-one. If we use a rather large number and don't have it's factors beforehand, then we can't do anything. Am I correct in that conclusion?

Comment: Many of these algebraic methods only work modulo prime numbers, and there are ways to extend solutions to prime *powers*. Indeed if $n$ is too large to factor, then solving such congruences can become very difficult. There are of course alternatives, but this is a whole field of study of its own so I won't go into details here.

Comment: Can you please tell me what alternatives fields are you talking about? I might find them interesting for further studies.

Comment: You can find an sketch of how to factor a polynomial mod a prime power on [this webpage](https://www.alpertron.com.ar/POLFACT.HTM). It includes references to some of the more advanced methods used for high degree polynomials and large moduli. The roots of the polynomial correspond to its linear factors. As I mentioned in the answer, the Chinese remainder theorem gives a bijection between solutions mod $n$ and solutions mod all prime powers dividing $n$.

Comment: Thank you! One more thing,  in your answer, when you said "8  solutions to the original congruence" and then gave  "m≡0,10,18,28,30,40,48,58 (mod 60)". I don't know how you got that. I'm a beginner in modular arithmetic, may be that's why. Can you please elaborate that part a bit more in your answer?

Comment: These are the $8$ congruence classes that satisfy the three congruences given just before that sentence. The first and last congruence together imply that $m\equiv0,8\pmod{10}$, and so there are just a few numbers to check. I suggest you read up on the Chinese remainder theorem, and try some examples. This really becomes much clearer after going through some examples by yourself. There are plenty of examples on this forum.

Comment: Yes, I was just reading up on that. Interestingly enough, my last question also ended up related to prime factors of the variable, which led me to modular arithmetic in the first place. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Let's rewrite your espression by adding and subtracting 1:

$$ (m+1) ^2- 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{60}$$

Which is equivalent to

$$ (m+1) ^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{60}$$

So we are looking for a perfect square that is just 1 next a multiple of 60. Let's change perspective: we are looking for a number 1 next to a multiple of 60 that is a perfect square. So let's begin by listing the numbers of the form $60n+1$ and see if we can spot a perfect square: $1, 61,121, \ldots$ Here it is! Thus $(m+1) ^2 = 121$ is the minimal solution, which gives $m=10$.

Comment: I like this approach, but it can only work for small numbers. I was looking for a more generalized formula.